# Where can I find this Data for the recent year period?

Tags: data, open-source

Im looking to do some data analysis with the most recent US census/estimates.
Im looking for this exact data in the link below . This data mostly spans time period 2007-2013.

`https://www.kaggle.com/code/spaghettiidawg666/primary-election-analysis-2016/data`

sample view of the data :-

| fips | area_name | state_abbreviation | PST045214 | PST040210 | PST120214 | POP010210 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | United States | 318857056 | 308758105 | 3.3 | 308745538 |  |
| 1000 | Alabama | 4849377 | 4780127 | 1.4 | 4779736 |  |
| 1001 | Autauga County | AL | 55395 | 54571 | 1.5 | 54571 |
| 1003 | Baldwin County | AL | 200111 | 182265 | 9.8 | 182265 |
| 1005 | Barbour County | AL | 26887 | 27457 | -2.1 | 27457 |
| 1007 | Bibb County | AL | 22506 | 22919 | -1.8 | 22915 |
| 1009 | Blount County | AL | 57719 | 57322 | 0.7 | 57322 |
| 1011 | Bullock County | AL | 10764 | 10915 | -1.4 | 10914 |
| 1013 | Butler County | AL | 20296 | 20946 | -3.1 | 20947 |
| 1015 | Calhoun County | AL | 115916 | 118586 | -2.3 | 118572 |
| 1017 | Chambers County | AL | 34076 | 34170 | -0.3 | 34215 |

I believe this was extrtacted from some older archive of `https://www.census.gov/quickfacts/fact/table/US/PST045221`.

I am looking for all these columns like Per Capita Income, Retail Sales,Retail Per capita on a county level(fips) available most *recently* as of today.

Can anybody help how to get it?
TIA

Comment: there is an open data SE for which this question would be better suited...

Comment: I know I think I dont have enough reputation to use tht tag